# Как получить значение data в теге select option?

Tags: jquery

При помощи jquery необходимо взять значение data из выбранного option. Пытался сделать при помощи selected, но он берет самый первый option на котором саморучно написан атрибут selected...

```
<select id="product-select" required>
    <option value="Выбранный пакет услуг" disabled selected>Выбранный пакет услуг</option>
    <option data-price="14 800" value="Minimum">Minimum</option>
    <option data-price="21 800" value="Basic">Basic</option>
    <option data-price="32 800" value="Premium">Premium</option>
</select>

$('#product-select').on('change', function () {
    $val = $('#product-select option:selected').data(price);
    $('.buy-popup__price').attr('value', $val + ' рублей');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#product-select').on('change', function () {
    $val = $('#product-select option:selected').data("price");
    $('.buy-popup__price').attr('value', $val + ' рублей');
});
$('#product-select').change();
$('#product-select').focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="product-select" required>
    <option value="Выбранный пакет услуг" disabled>Выбранный пакет услуг</option>
    <option data-price="14 800" value="Minimum">Minimum</option>
    <option data-price="21 800" value="Basic">Basic</option>
    <option selected data-price="32 800" value="Premium">Premium</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="buy-popup__price" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="product-select" required>
<option value="Выбранный пакет услуг" disabled selected>Выбранный пакет услуг</option>
<option data-price="14 800" value="Minimum">Minimum</option>
<option data-price="21 800" value="Basic">Basic</option>
<option data-price="32 800" value="Premium">Premium</option>
```

`$('#product-select').on('change', function () {
    $val = $(this).parent().find('option:selected').data('price')
    $('.buy-popup__price').attr('value', $val + ' рублей');
});`